# Unable to locate a ejb in spring context

Tags: spring, ejb

I am trying to use a EJB singleton bean inside of spring bean but somehow it unable to locate a this ejb and getting a message when run a server:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationFailureHandler' defined in class path resource [spring-security-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginAttemptService' while setting bean property 'loginAttemptService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'loginAttemptService' is defined
```

Here is a EJB:

```
public interface ILoginAttemptService {

    public boolean checkout(String username);
}
```

Here is implementation:

```
@Slf4j
@Stateless(name = "loginAttemptService")
@Singleton
public class LoginAttemptsService implements ILoginAttemptService {
..
}
```

In spring framework this is how i define a stateless bean:

```
<bean id="loginAttemptServiceBean"
          class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"
                  value="java:app/osloproject-ejb/loginAttemptService"/>
        <property name="businessInterface"
                  value="com.hospitality.hp.securitycommons.api.ILoginAttemptService"/>
    </bean>




 <bean id="authSuccessHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="redirectStrategy">
            <bean class="com.hospitality.hp.securitycommons.tools.spring.CORSCompatibleTwoFactorAuthenticationRedirectStrategy">

                <property name="loginAttemptService" ref="loginAttemptServiceBean"/>

            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
      class="com.hospitality.hp.securitycommons.tools.spring.AuthenticationFailureCustomHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
    <property name="loginAttemptService" ref="loginAttemptServiceBean"/>

</bean>
```

Can someone tell me why it unable to find the JNDI name of this EJB ?

Comment: `@Stateless @Singleton`..? This is self-condratictory in first place. Use the one or other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<jee:local-slsb id="loginAttemptServiceBean" jndi-name="java:app/osloproject-ejb/loginAttemptService"
                business-interface="com.hospitality.hp.securitycommons.api.ILoginAttemptService"/>
```

"jee" is Spring’s namespace.and also check the jndi-name value is correct

Comment: Let me try like this, Can you tell me what will be scope of bean using this way? still singleton ?